# Using Stack Exchange for my students

Tags: support

I teach a course in C++ and want my students to post questions about the course material in a professional forum, and have other students answer them. They do not use Stack Overflow directly due to several reasons:

- Their questions are often specific to the course, e.g. "what did you mean in slide 39?" or "why doesn't my code compile in the automatic homework grader?". On Stack Overflow they will probably be closed.
- Many of them are not good at writing in English. If they post in Stack Overflow, their post will have to be massively edited for grammar errors.

Is there a way to open a new Stack Overflow-like forum that will be specific to a class? It does not have to be secret - I don't mind if outside developers will also post questions or answers. All I need is to moderate the forum myself, so that I can allow questions specific to the course and in the students' native tongue (Hebrew).

Comment: [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) is probably the best way to go, as the answerer mentions.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question: there is not a way to create a whole new SE site solely for the use of your students.

> Their questions are often specific to the course, e.g. "what did you mean in slide 39?" or "why doesn't my code compile in the automatic homework grader?". In stackoverflow they will probably be closed.

Being specific to a course doesn't automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow. As long as it still complies with [the on-topic help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and any other rules for being on-topic.

> Is there a way to open a new stackoverflow-like forum that will be specific to a class?

As I said before, no, you can't open an entirely new forum just for the use of your students. You can, however, use [Stack Overflow for teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) if you want to keep your class's questions private.

> All I need is to moderate the forum myself, so that I can allow questions specific to the course and in the students' native tongue (Hebrew).

If you want a SE site in a different language, you'll have to go through [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) to get your site launched. Unfortunately, Area 51 isn't currently accepting proposals for non-English sites, so this couldn't be done right now.